# How to add a subfolder to a project in visual studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I am new to c++ and visual studio.

The project was successfully building when I had the following structure on my disc:

```
project
│   main.cpp
│   phantom.cpp
│   phantom.h
│   organ.cpp
│   organ.h
│   spectrum.cpp
│   spectrum.h
│   paticle.cpp
│   particle.h
│   simulation.cpp
│   simulation.h
```

This is how project was looking in visual studio:

```
project
└───Header Files
│   ├──   phantom.h
│   ├──   organ.h
│   ├──   spectrum.h
│   ├──   particle.h
│   └──   simulation.h
└─── Source Files
     ├──   main.cpp
     ├──   phantom.cpp
     ├──   organ.cpp
     ├──   spectrum.cpp
     ├──   paticle.cpp  
     └──   simulation.cpp
```

Then I decided to create subfolders and moved some `.h` and `.cpp` files into them. Here is the current structure of the project on my disc:

```
project
│    main.cpp
└─── Phantom
│    ├──   phantom.h
│    ├──   organ.h
│    ├──   phantom.cpp
│    └──   organ.cpp
└─── Physics
     ├──   simulation.cpp
     ├──   simulation.h
     ├──   spectrum.cpp
     ├──   spectrum.h
     ├──   paticle.cpp 
     └──   particle.h
```

Added filters and moved corresponding files in VS:

```
project
└───Header Files
│   └─── Phantom
│   │    ├──   phantom.h
│   │    ├──   organ.h
│   └─── Physics
│        ├──   spectrum.h
│        ├──   particle.h
│        └──   simulation.h
└───Source Files
│   └─── Phantom
│   │    ├──   phantom.cpp
│   │    └──   organ.cpp
│   └─── Physics
│   │    ├──   spectrum.cpp
│   │    ├──   paticle.cpp  
│   │    └──   simulation.cpp
│   └──  main.cpp
```

**Problem:**
I am getting LNK2001 and LNK2019 errors. From my understanding, the problem is that linker can not link definitions of functions in `.h` to the implementations in `.cpp`.

main.cpp

```
#include "Phantom/phantom.h"
#include "Physics/simulation.h"
```

simulation.cpp

```
#include "../Phantom/phantom.h"
```

The path to the project has already been included in Properties->C/C++->Additional Include Directories

**Question:** What is a proper way of adding subfolder to a project in visual studio 2022? How do you structure your projects?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a C++ guy. But in general, if you have some namespace setting in your code reflect your folder changes to namespaces. Also, maybe it is wise not use spaces in folder names. Hope this helps.